# How to get mouse state from within an mxj object in Max/MSP

Tags: java, max-msp-jitter

From inside an mxj object, is there any way to determine whether any mouse buttons are currently pressed?

I know that in a Max patch this data can be gathered from a [mousestate] object. I'd like to do the same sort of thing, but from within my Java code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After many hours of searching, I couldn't figure out any way to get at the mouse state data from within the mxj object. I'm not sure it's possible. I ended up working out a clunky solution using [mousestate] instead.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to get the mouse position.

```
public void bang() {
        Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        post(""+p.getX());
}
```

Getting the mouse state should be really easy with the help of the code above.